# How to sum a triple nested map with Java 8 Collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have this map
Map<LocalDate, Map<Integer, Map<EHourQuarter, Double>>>

EHourQuarter is an enum:

```
public enum EHourQuarter {
    FIRST(0, 14, 15),
    SECOND(15, 29, 30),
    THIRD(30, 44, 45),
    FOURTH(45, 59, 60);

    private Integer start;
    private Integer end;
    private Integer value;//this is for UI purposes
}
```

With values like:
{2020-07-07 -> {0 -> {EHourQuarter.FIRST -> 5.5, EHourQuarter.SECOND -> 10.2, ...},
1 -> {EHourQuarter.FIRST -> 33.2, EHourQuarter.SECOND -> 30.1, ...}, ...},

2020-07-08 -> {0 -> {EHourQuarter.FIRST -> 5.5, EHourQuarter.SECOND -> 10.2, ...},
1 -> {EHourQuarter.FIRST -> 33.2, EHourQuarter.SECOND -> 30.1, ...}, ... }

It's a map of LocalDate of map of Integer (hour: from 0 to 23) of map of EHourQuarter of Double.

And I need to get a Map<Integer(hour), Map<EHourQuarter, Double>> containing the accumulated of every date, meaning that if dates 2020-07-07 to 2020-07-10 (4 days) contained in hour 0 each one 5 for every EHourQuarter, then the result should show in hour 0, each quarter with a value of 20.

Additionally, if by making that you could help me also with mapping that to a List of DTOs like this ones,

```
public class QuarterlyOccupancyDTO {
    private Integer hour;
    private Integer minute;//this is the value property of EHourQuarter
    private Double occupancy;
}
```

I'd much appreciate it.

At the end, the list of DTOs should contain the sum of all dates grouped by hour and minute (value property of EHourQuarter).

This is an example.

***NOTE: a map can contain multiple dates and the aim is to group/sum all .***

Given this map:

```
{
   "2020-06-26":{
      "0":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "1":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "2":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "3":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "4":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "5":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "6":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "7":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "8":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "9":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "10":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "11":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "12":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "13":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "14":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "15":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "16":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "17":{
         "FOURTH":5.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":5.0,
         "SECOND":5.0
      },
      "18":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":5.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "19":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "20":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "21":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "22":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      },
      "23":{
         "FOURTH":0.0,
         "FIRST":0.0,
         "THIRD":0.0,
         "SECOND":0.0
      }
   }
}
```

A list like this should be the answer:

```
[
   {
      "hour":0,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":0,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":0,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":0,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":1,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":1,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":1,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":1,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":2,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":2,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":2,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":2,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":3,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":3,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":3,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":3,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":4,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":4,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":4,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":4,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":5,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":5,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":5,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":5,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":6,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":6,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":6,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":6,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":7,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":7,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":7,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":7,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":8,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":8,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":8,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":8,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":9,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":9,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":9,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":9,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":10,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":10,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":10,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":10,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":11,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":11,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":11,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":11,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":12,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":12,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":12,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":12,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":13,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":13,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":13,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":13,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":14,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":14,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":14,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":14,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":15,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":15,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":15,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":15,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":16,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":16,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":16,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":16,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":17,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":17,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":17,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":17,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":18,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":5.0
   },
   {
      "hour":18,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":18,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":18,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":19,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":19,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":19,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":19,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":20,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":20,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":20,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":20,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":21,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":21,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":21,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":21,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":22,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":22,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":22,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":22,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":23,
      "minute":15,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":23,
      "minute":30,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":23,
      "minute":45,
      "occupancy":0.0
   },
   {
      "hour":23,
      "minute":60,
      "occupancy":0.0
   }
]
```

Comment: Add your tried approach so far  in post

Answer (score 1):

First using `flatMap` create `Stream<SimpleEntry<Integer, EHourQuarter>, Double>` then using `toMap` collect as `Map<SimpleEntry<Integer, EHourQuarter>, Double>`. Then map into you DTO class.

```
List<QuarterlyOccupancyDTO> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(d -> d.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(h -> h.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(
                e -> new SimpleEntry<>(new SimpleEntry<>(h.getKey(), e.getKey()), e.getValue()))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a + b))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(m -> new QuarterlyOccupancyDTO(m.getKey().getKey(), m.getKey().getValue().getValue(), m.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Note*: As you don't show your code some part may not work. Full code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rJm4rXmJw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'm gonna use the other option presented by ETO since I find it more readable

Answer (score 1):

First group and sum the occupancy by hour/quarter pair

(Avoid nested `flatMap`, as it makes code less readable)

```
Map<Entry<Integer, Integer>, Double> groups
    = map.entrySet()
         .stream()
         // Flatten the outer map, since you don't care about the days
         .flatMap(de -> de.getValue().entrySet().stream())
         // Flatten the map by combining hour key and quarter key into a single one
         .flatMap(he -> he.getValue()
                          .entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .map(qe -> new SimpleEntry<>(new SimpleEntry<>(he.getKey(), qe.getKey().getValue()), qe.getValue())))
         // Sum the occupancy per each hour/quarter pair
         .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, summingDouble(Entry::getValue)));
```

Then map the grouped entries into your DTO objects

```
List<QuarterlyOccupancyDTO> list =
    groups.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(e -> new QuarterlyOccupancyDTO(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()))
          .collect(toList());
```

---

Another pure functional approach:

(It's pure, but seems less readable, IMO)

```
Collection<QuarterlyOccupancyDTO> dtos =
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       // Flatten the outer map, since you don't care about the days
       .flatMap(de -> de.getValue().entrySet()
                        .stream())
       // Flatten the map by merging hour key and quarter key into a single one
       .flatMap(he -> he.getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(qe -> new SimpleEntry<>(new SimpleEntry<>(he.getKey(), qe.getKey().getValue()),
                                                     qe.getValue())))
       // Map each entry into a DTO object and then reduce the occupancy per each hour/quarter pair
       .collect(
           groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                      mapping(e -> new QuarterlyOccupancyDTO(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()),
                              reducing(new QuarterlyOccupancyDTO(0, 0, 0.0),
                                       (a, b) -> new QuarterlyOccupancyDTO(b.getHour(), b.getMinute(), a.getOccupancy() + b.getOccupancy())))))
       .values();
```

Comment: What is the difference between your solution with other answer ?

Comment: @RiwimoHerbs 1. do not use **nested** flatmapping. 2. `summingDouble` instead of using merge function. 3. Intermediary variable instead of chaining 2 pipelines (minor change)

Comment: Most of the idea is same you are doing just some minor change, it's better to comment to update minor change. Hope you understand.

Comment: @RiwimoHerbs Your vote belongs to you. Feel free to cast it however and whenever you want. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341528/10584605

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree that this is more readable, ETO